# Javascript textarea charcoutner isn't working

Tags: javascript

hello my code isn't working idk why  i tried to make textarea char counter that only shows the chachter not maxiumum
here is the java script

```js
let text = document.querySelector('#text');
let number = text.value.length;
let count = document.querySelector('#count');   

text.addEventListener("input", updateCount());

function updateCount(){
count.value + number
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Karakter sayısı</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ses">
        <textarea  id="text" placeholder="Yazıyı buraya Kopyala veya Yaz"></textarea>
    </div>
  <span id="filhu">Bu kadar yazdın:</span><span id="count">0</span>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @d0rf47 Variable scope? How so…? The calculation result isn’t being stored, `number` is always = 0 as the value is not updated on the event… among other issues, but I don’t believe variable scope is at all at play here. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your  `text.addEventListener("input", updateCount());` assignment you did *not* assign the function `updateCount` to the `input` event of the selected element but instead you *executed* it once and assigned the non-existent return value of the function call to the event.

And in the function itself you will need to *put* (=assign) the calculated count somewhere too:

```js
let text = document.querySelector('#text');
let count = document.querySelector('#count');   

text.addEventListener("input", updateCount);

function updateCount(ev){
  count.textContent=ev.target.value.length;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Karakter sayısı</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ses">
        <textarea  id="text" placeholder="Yazıyı buraya Kopyala veya Yaz"></textarea>
    </div>
  <span id="filhu">Bu kadar yazdın:</span><span id="count">0</span>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`ev.target.value.length` gets the current length of the `<textarea>` element and `count.textContent=` assigns it to the target `<span>`.

Comment: Presumably because your initial answer was nothing but a code-dump, without any explanation. That doesn't really help OP understand what they did wrong, nor is it helpful to any future visitors. That's low quality in my book.

Comment: @ivar thanks for providing the explanation. Perfectly clear about the "code dumping" thing. I was in the middle of finishing the explanation to my post when the downvote was already fired on me. Give me a break :D for goodness sake! (ROFL) ... or at least 5 minutes to finish my sentence.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is by subscribing to the keyup event and getting the value from the scope using `this` keyword

```js
function characterCount() {
  document.getElementById('text').onkeyup = function () {
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = this.value.length;
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Karakter sayısı</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ses">
        <textarea id="text" placeholder="Yazıyı buraya Kopyala veya Yaz" onchange="characterCount()"></textarea>
    </div>
    <span id="filhu">Bu kadar yazdın:</span><span id="count">0</span>
</body>

</html>
```